# Oddity with using || for assignment where Conditional (ternary) operator is second option

Tags: javascript, syntax, ternary-operator

Caught a bug in my code, where I'm using `foo = bar || baz` to assign to baz if bar is undefined, however when using a ternary expression for the second argument, JS would assign the true value for the ternary expression, regardless of the first value.

Opened up the console and tested it. Seems that JS doesn't even evaluate the conditional expression, as seen here, where b isn't defined, but it still returns the true value for it.

```
>>> a = 1 || 2
1
>>> a = 0 || 2
2
>>> a = 1 || b
1
>>> a = 1 || b ? 3 : 4
3
>>> b
ReferenceError: b is not defined[Learn More]
>>> a = 1 || ( b ? 3 : 4 )
1
```

I am able to get the correct result by wrapping the ternary expression in ()s, but what's going on here? Why does it return 3 in the above test-case?

Comment: The logical OR has a higher precedence than the conditional operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table. *"Operators with higher precedence become the operands of operators with lower precedence."*

Comment: Your statement is equivalent to `a = (1 || b) ? 3 : 4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`||` is *lazy* - it will not attempt to evaluate the right-hand side of a `||` of the left-hand side is determined to be truthy. If you had done `b || 1` instead of `1 || b`, it would have tried to evaluate `b` first, and an error would be thrown:

```js
const a = b || 1 ? 3 : 4
```

The *whole left side* of the `?` is interpreted to be the condition. (Other operations performed on the left of a `?` will also be parsed before the whole `?` condition is evaluated.) The conditional operator has one of the [lowest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table) operator precedences.

For

```
1 || b ? 3 : 4
```

the operator with the highest precedence there is `||`, at 5. So the two expressions across from the `||` get evaluated for "or" first:

```
1 || b
```

Since 1 is truthy, the whole `1 || b` evaluates to `1` without considering `b`.

```
1 ? 3 : 4
```

Then the conditional operator is evaluated (precedence 4):

```
true ? 3 : 4
```

evaluates to

```
3
```

because the condition is true.

When you put parentheses around the conditional:

```
1 || ( b ? 3 : 4 )
```

Parentheses have the *highest operator precedence*, at 20 - the interpreter knows that everything inside the parentheses will evaluate to a single expression, without regard to what's outside the parentheses. So

```
1 || <something>
```

evaluates to

```
1
```

because 1 is truthy.

Comment: Read the example code again, problem is that dispite || being lazy it **is** going to the right side, and the ternary expression isn't even being evaulated correctly, as b isn't even defined, but it's returning the truth case of it. when it should return 1.

Comment: That's how operator precedence works - because the conditional has so low precedence, if you want to force the evaluation of the `b ? 3 : 4` together, you need to put it in parentheses.

Comment: Why does the following eval to 5 `a = true || false ? 5: 60` ? That's what I'm wondering, and you're not really getting to.
Correclty  `false || false ? 5: 60` evals to 60, 

Ah, I see the issue, now. The expression is being evaluated as (true || false) ? 5 : 60.